# Strange left-to-right arrows while running postgresql scripts

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql

I want to run about 5000 lines of postgresql scripts. For professional reasons, I can't share the whole content of the script. 
But I have something a bit like this :

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
...
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.client DROP CONSTRAINT client_pkey;
...
ALTER TABLE public.client ALTER COLUMN id DROP DEFAULT;
...
DROP SEQUENCE public.client_id_seq;
DROP TABLE public.client;
...
--
-- Name: client; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: myDB; Tablespace: 
--

CREATE TABLE client (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    libelle character varying(255)
);


ALTER TABLE client OWNER TO myDB;

--
-- Name: client_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: myDB
--

CREATE SEQUENCE client_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE client_id_seq OWNER TO myDB;

--
-- Name: client_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: myDB
--
--
-- Data for Name: client; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: myDB
--

COPY client (id, libelle) FROM stdin;
0
1   XX
247 YY
248 ZZ
\.
```

There is a lot of insertions with the `copy` statement. But everytime I run the DB, I get something like this with a lot of left-to-right arrows:
[image]

And I don't know how to continue. When I check my database out, the overall script isn't totally run. Only the tables are created.
Please, what's the problem ?

PS: I use Linux Debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `COPY FROM STDIN` you see message:

```
t=# copy s151 from stdin;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
```

the key here is

> End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself

So your multiple `>>` just means that a new row has added to COPY from stdin. Seing those is absolutely OK. You will see those on every new line until you put `\.` on it

Now regarding the problem. Your script has error (I copy/pasted a part of it):

```
t=# \! cat so.sql
CREATE TABLE client (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    libelle character varying(255)
);
COPY client (id, libelle) FROM stdin;
0
1   XX
247 YY
248 ZZ
\.

t=# \i so.sql
CREATE TABLE
psql:so.sql:10: ERROR:  missing data for column "libelle"
CONTEXT:  COPY client, line 1: "0"
```

After I add missing column (and change delimiter to space to avoid tabulation problems when copying from webpage):

```
t=# \! cat so.sql
COPY client (id, libelle) FROM stdin delimiter ' ';
0 ZZ
1 XX
247 YY
248 ZZ
\.
t=# \i so.sql
COPY 4
```

It works

Comment: I think the missing column value is just a result of copy & paste. If the original file contained a tab character after the `0` then everything would be fine (the value would `null` then for `libelle`)

Comment: yes, it would. But the all rows would be copied - OP has ending `\.`... I tried to guess the reason for not having data copied

Comment: sure - glad to help